# Losing memory application

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, maverick

I have a 2009 Mac Book Pro.  Just added 8 G of memory.  It filled that memory in 10 minutes.
I have to force quite up to five times a day.

If you offer help please use lay terms as I cannot understand half of what I read on the these boards.

I spent two weeks on Apple boards and we tried everything.  NOte that I am just one many with the same problem.  I think it has to do with Maverick.

Basically I am leaking memory like a sieve.

Comment: It not the OS I guarantee you that you have some process to blame boot into the most minimal configuration you can and report back

Comment: Well if you've "tried everything" then how can we suggest anything new? ;)  What EXACTLY have you tried already?  What were the results?

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac is not leaking memory. Apple has changed the way your system uses the memory in Mavericks. It [caches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) data in the memory to improve start up performance of the applications that you use the most.

This link goes into more detail: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5470580?tstart=0

As vea1083 states

> Mavericks now has a memory compression feature that will compress the memory occupied by applications that aren't being actively used and give the freed up RAM to the application that needs it the most. The result is a much more responsive system and less memory being dumped to a swap file to the HDD which is what reduces the performance of your Mac.
>
> If I were you, I would not look at the RAM used number but rather to the Memory Pressure graph that tells you how stressed is the system in terms of memory.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you edited your answer to contain the relevant parts of the discussion link you posted, as to prevent link-rot.